# Error in get data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, jet

I'm trying to get data from Excel file using:

```
OpenFileDialog OpenCSVDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenCSVDialog.Filter = "Excel |*.xlsx";
            OpenCSVDialog.ShowDialog();
            ExcelFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenCSVDialog.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCSVDialog.FileName);
            fullpath = Path.Combine(path, ExcelFileName);

            dt_data = new DataSet("CSV File");
            var connString = string.Format(
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""",
                Path.GetDirectoryName(fullpath)
            );
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var query = "SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(fullpath) + "]";
                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt_data);
                }

            }
```

but when browsing see error coming in this line: `adapter.Fill(dt_data);`:

[image]

I have the Excel file in related path.

Comment: Please show the line where the exception *occured*, not where it was caught. Most likely though, you need to escape the filename, eg write `Data Source='{0}'`

Comment: Edited the question. Please check

Comment: Just noticed that you are using the filename in the `FROM` clause. `FROM` is used to select from a specific *sheet*, not file. It should be something like `FROM [Sheet1$]` .

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM [...]` clause specifies which sheet (actually, range) you want to read from. It should contain the sheet's name, not the workbook's filename.

If your sheet is called `Sheet1`, you should use

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
```

There are many answers in SO that show how to extract the first sheet's name if it isn't known etc.

**UPDATE**

I also noticed that you use the file's directory path in the connection string instead of the full path. You should use the full file path instead:

```
 var connString = string.Format(
            @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""",
            fullpath
        );
```

Comment: when using this following error showing. "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$.txt'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

Comment: What did you try? Did you use the file path as data source or something else,  like the directory?

Comment: I changed only this part. "var query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

Comment: Your connection string though uses the *directory's* path as a data source instead of the file's. You should change it to use the full file path

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code . Now its working.

```
OpenFileDialog OpenCSVDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenCSVDialog.Filter = "Excel |*.xls";
            OpenCSVDialog.ShowDialog();
            ExcelFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenCSVDialog.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenCSVDialog.FileName);
            fullpath = Path.Combine(path, ExcelFileName);

            dt_data = new DataSet("CSV File");

            string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
          "Data Source=" + fullpath +
          ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;'";

            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");

                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt_data);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

See my class below.  Look at the splitting of the full filename into a path and filename.

```
public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }​
```

Comment: Why is this an answer to the OP's question? Posting some code and waiting for others to discover what it does is *not* considered a good practice in SO. If you wanted to say that the `FROM` statement should change, say it explicitly. Not that it will solve the problem though - `FROM` refers to the *sheet* not the file

Comment: Because it is better to put this code into a class that to make it inline code.  Since I developed this code a year ago it was better to post a better method than just to answer the question.  Let the op solve is own issue by looking at code that actually works.